# Naming Conventions в Java - почему не рекомендуется использовать знак нижнего подчеркивания в именовании пакетов?

Tags: java

В туториале:
"Legalizing Package Names 
Package Name Prefix 
org.example.hyphenated_name"
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html

Эклипс же призывает избегать:
"Package names should contain only lowercase ASCII alphanumerics, and avoid underscore _ or dollar sign $ characters."
https://wiki.eclipse.org/Naming_Conventions

Здесь же так и не пришли к общему знаменателю. Главы, на которые ссылаются при обосновании ответов удалены из спецификаций.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179216/what-is-the-convention-for-word-separator-in-java-package-names

Comment: я помню одну проблему - использование `JNI`, там точки в имени класса заменяются на _, сами _ остаются. Из-за этого были проблемы со сборкой когда-то.

Comment: Потому что это уже становится не reverse domain notation.

Comment: @Etki спасибо, помогло